# Append a text to input field without changing its value?

Tags: html, css, typescript, input

I have an input field with type "number", but I want to append text " days" inside that input field value without changing the actual value that comes out of it.

```
<input type="number" class="days" (keyup)="valueChanged($event)"/>
```

If the user changes the value, they should be able to change only the numerical value and the appended " days" is only visual *addon* to that field.

Is there a way to do it in CSS or TypeScript/JS?

Comment: Do you beforehand know how many integers the user can/will use?

Comment: The additional string you want to append to the value should simply reside in a sibling element after the `<input>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of inserting the unit into the input why not have a specific style of input for these scenarios where you can append or prepend any unit. Something like:

```css
.unit-input {
  border: #DFDFDF solid 1px;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  width: 10em;
}

.unit-input__input {
  border: 0;
  padding: .5em;
  font-size: 1em;
  width: 100%;
}

.unit-input__input:focus {
  background: #EDFFFB;
  outline: none;
}

.unit-input__prepend,
.unit-input__append {
  background: #F4F4F4;
  padding: .5em;
  border: #DFDFDF solid 0;
  flex-grow: 0;
}

.unit-input__prepend {
  border-right-width: 1px;
}

.unit-input__append {
  border-left-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="unit-input">
    <input class="unit-input__input" type="number">
    <span class="unit-input__append">days</span>
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="unit-input">
    <span class="unit-input__prepend">$</span>
    <input class="unit-input__input" type="number">
  </span>
</p>

<p>
  <span class="unit-input">
    <input class="unit-input__input" type="number">
    <span class="unit-input__append">kg</span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this somewhat cheaply by simply sticking a span after the input and applying a negative margin-right to the input:

```
<input type='number' style='margin-right: -10em;'><span>days</span>
```

That way you aren't touching your data at all and it remains purely cosmetic.

Answer (score 0):

You could absolute position a span or :after at the end of the input. This is more useful if you actually know the length of the input however. Otherwise I would use JS to calculate width of the input and append it.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  position: relative;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.wrapper:after {
  content: 'kg';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: .5rem;
  pointer-events: none;
}

input {
  width: 4rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="100">
</div>
```